# Should I change the axis or the degree for making flip upwards/downwards?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I would want it to flip up/down rather than left/light, so my question is do I need to change the axis or the angle? I'm trying since 2 hours by nothing seems to get that work. Please guide me through this. Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GHK5h).

**HTML**

```
<div class="flip" style="width: X.px; height: X.px;">
    <a href="#">
        <div class="flip-front">
            <img src="http://divabetic.files.wordpress.com/2012/07/dai-mcdonalds-400-calories280.jpg">
        </div>
           <div class="flip-back">
            <img src="http://divabetic.files.wordpress.com/2012/07/dai-mcdonalds-400-calories280.jpg">
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.flip {
    position: relative;
    -webkit-perspective: 1000;
    -moz-perspective: 1000;
    -ms-perspective: 1000;
    -o-perspective: 1000;
    perspective: 1000;
}
.flip .flip-front, .flip .flip-back {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: 0.75s;
    -moz-transition: 0.75s;
    -o-transition: 0.75s;
    transition: 0.75s;
}
.flip .flip-front {
    z-index: 5;
}
.flip .flip-back {
    z-index: 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    -o-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    transform: rotateY(-180deg);

}
.flip:hover .flip-front {
    z-index: 5;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(270deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(270deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(270deg);
    -o-transform: rotateY(270deg);
    transform: rotateY(270deg);
}
.flip:hover .flip-back {
    z-index: 5;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateX(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateX(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotateX(0deg);
    transform: rotateX(0deg);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please, aways add the relevant code to your question, to make in self contained.

Answer (score 1):

You want to change the axis of rotation, to the X axis in your case. Basically, use `rotateX()` instead of `rotateY()` So here's the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GYatesIII/GHK5h/1/) and the CSS:

```
.flip {
    position: relative;
    -webkit-perspective: 1000;
    -moz-perspective: 1000;
    -ms-perspective: 1000;
    -o-perspective: 1000;
    perspective: 1000;
}
.flip .flip-front, .flip .flip-back {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: 0.75s;
    -moz-transition: 0.75s;
    -o-transition: 0.75s;
    transition: 0.75s;
}
.flip .flip-front {
    z-index: 5;
}
.flip .flip-back {
    z-index: 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateX(-180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateX(-180deg);
    -o-transform: rotateX(-180deg);
    transform: rotateX(-180deg);

}
.flip:hover .flip-front {
    z-index: 5;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(270deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateX(270deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateX(270deg);
    -o-transform: rotateX(270deg);
    transform: rotateX(270deg);
}
.flip:hover .flip-back {
    z-index: 5;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateX(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateX(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotateX(0deg);
    transform: rotateX(0deg);
}
```

There's still some weird double rotation happening, but since that was present in your example, I didn't try to fix it as I'm not sure exactly what effect you're going for.

---

**EDIT:**

Also, if I understand what's going on, you have an unnecessary duplicate element in there. Here I've removed the extra element and modified the CSS for the same effect by rotating the single element 360 degrees instead of two 180 degrees each. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GYatesIII/GHK5h/6/). I've also modified the code to apply an absolute width and height to the `.flip` div so that you don't get the double rotation in Firefox as the div collapses when the element rotates.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="flip"> 
    <a href="#">
        <div class="flip-front">
            <img src="http://divabetic.files.wordpress.com/2012/07/dai-mcdonalds-400-calories280.jpg">
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.flip {
    position: relative;
    -webkit-perspective: 1000;
    -moz-perspective: 1000;
    -ms-perspective: 1000;
    -o-perspective: 1000;
    perspective: 1000;
    height: 186px;
    width: 280px;
}
.flip .flip-front {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: 0.75s;
    -moz-transition: 0.75s;
    -o-transition: 0.75s;
    transition: 0.75s;
}
.flip .flip-front {
    z-index: 5;
}
.flip:hover .flip-front {
    z-index: 5;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(360deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateX(360deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateX(360deg);
    -o-transform: rotateX(360deg);
    transform: rotateX(360deg);
}
```

Comment: I've done that but the thing is dont you feel its rotating slightly on to left?

Comment: Sorry, I don't see anything except a rotation over the axis. And looking at the code since there's no Y axis rotation, it shouldn't be anything but purely around the X. Here's an updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GYatesIII/GHK5h/5/) that removes the double element and flips the single element a full 360 degrees for the same effect.

Comment: Here's another [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GYatesIII/GHK5h/6/) with the double rotation fixed in Firefox. I've edited my answer to include this extra information.

Comment: Geprge! Thanx for that but its just flipping the front face isn't it?

Comment: and what i was thinking was to flip two div with different content in each

Comment: Oh, if you're looking to put different content in the two, then you're correct to maintain two versions. [Here's a fiddle with a different image for the backface to make it more clear what's going on](http://jsfiddle.net/GYatesIII/GHK5h/8/). In that fiddle, I've maintained the other changes though, flipping over the X axis, only flipping 180 degrees instead of 270, and setting an absolute size on `.flip` to prevent div collpase in Firefox.

Comment: Thanks @ George Yates! It was really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned flip:hover two times, that will override the previous one & there is no need to use back part of image that you used filp-back & front. In the rotation part use rotateX(360deg) . This will provide you the perfect solution of the thing that you want.
>

jsfiddle link
`jsfiddle`

Comment: He's actually flipping two elements with the `.flip:hover` state, one to rotate one way and the other to rotate back, I've addressed the efficiency of that in my answer.

Comment: @george you can look at jsfiddle. It is as perfect as you gave then why he is introducing more code, more image & going to have a heavy page.

Comment: I agree, but I was addressing this statement in your answer: "You mentioned flip:hover two times, that will override the previous one", this is not the case as he was altering two different children for the same parent hover state, there is no override going on.

Comment: ohh yea @george you are right .. I again checked the code & found it correct, it will not override.

Answer (score 0):

As George Yates said, you have to change the transform to rotateX.

Since you say that you want to have a different image in the back, this is your CSS:

```
.flip {
    position: relative;
    -webkit-perspective: 1000;
    -moz-perspective: 1000;
    -ms-perspective: 1000;
    -o-perspective: 1000;
    perspective: 1000;
    -webkit-perspective-origin-x: 140px;
    -moz-perspective-origin-x: 140px;
    -ms-perspective-origin-x: 140px;
    perspective-origin-x: 140px;
}
.flip .flip-front, .flip .flip-back {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: 0.75s;
    -moz-transition: 0.75s;
    -o-transition: 0.75s;
    transition: 0.75s;
}
.flip .flip-front {
    z-index: 5;
}
.flip .flip-back {
    z-index: 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateX(-180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateX(-180deg);
    -o-transform: rotateX(-180deg);
    transform: rotateX(-180deg);

}
.flip:hover .flip-front {
    z-index: 5;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateX(180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateX(180deg);
    -o-transform: rotateX(180deg);
    transform: rotateX(180deg);
}
.flip:hover .flip-back {
    z-index: 5;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateX(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateX(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotateX(0deg);
    transform: rotateX(0deg);
}
```

I have also added to the flip class a perspective origin to make your point of view centered. What you see as a rotation to the left is a perspective effect, you are looking to a centered rotation but your point of view is centered in the flip class, that is bigger than the image.

So, your point of view is to the right and makes the rotation look to the left. Seting the perspective origin x at 140px makes it in the center of the image

[updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vals/GHK5h/9/)